# Strongloop: updateAttributes method id parameter is undefined

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I'm implementing a connector for strongloop.

I try to updateAttributes by calling 
    PUT /api/entity/:id

My connector's updateAttributes method is hit but the id parameter is undefined.

```
myConnector.prototype.updateAttributes = function(model, id, body, callback) {
```

Other methods like all, create, delete work.

What is wrong?

loopback version: 2.14.0
node version: 0.10.36

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the id was passed as is /api/model/:id.
I had special Id name: _id. My model.json didn't have this definition.

```
"_id": {
    "type": "string",
    "id": true
}
```